# Binding Android events to Qt application

Tags: java, android, c++, qt, events

I have examined the auto-generated `QtActivity.java` and `QtApplication.java`, found the skeleton and actual implementations and the simple format they follow. However, from those two sources I could go only as far as the `m_delegateObject` Object in `QtApplication` which is the object on which methods are invoked upon receiving events from android.

But I still can't understand where does the delegate object come from. There is `public static void setQtActivityDelegate(Object listener)` but I have zero idea where this ends up being called. And since there is reflection being used on the delegate, I logically assume it is indeed yet another java object and not a delegate to the actual native application.

My question is how to reach to the actual C++ application and forward a custom event to it, using what mechanism (Qt meta, JNI...?).

Answer (score 0):

Didn't do what you ask exactly but if you receive the notification in java then you can call C++ code from java:

- In Java you have to declare the native function

> package com.test.util;
>   ...
>   private static native void CallCpp(String tag,int prm1,int prm2,int
>   prm3,String prmString);

and in the C++ side register the native fn

> ```
>     JNINativeMethod methods[] {{"CallCpp","(Ljava/lang/String;IIILjava/lang/String;)V", reinterpret_cast<void> *>(CallCpp)},
>                               };
>
>
>         QAndroidJniObject javaClass("com/tests/util/AndroidEnv");
>         QAndroidJniEnvironment env;
>         jclass objectClass = env->GetObjectClass(javaClass.object<jobject>());
>         env->RegisterNatives(objectClass, methods, sizeof(methods) / sizeof(methods[0]));
>         env->DeleteLocalRef(objectClass);
> ```